# multi-protocol transmitters -- difference between stm32 4-in-1 and stm32 c2500 only ? [tx16s Vs. tx12]

Tags: transmitter, antenna, long-range-drone, multiprotocol-module, transmitter-protocol

Searching on the radio controllers radiomaster TX16s and TX12,

[image]

I found that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekrG5meNZOU%3F&t=5m47s

that warns me that Tx16s has an internal stm32 4-in-1 protocols chip, whereas Tx12 has an stm32 c2500 "only", according to this opensource project website : https://downloads.multi-module.org/

1. What are the cons with the c2500 chip ? Does it handle less protocols ? Does it provide less power to the 2.4GHz antenna and thus reduces the range for sending commands?
2. What is spectrum protocol ? A brand of drones ? I often hear about these recceivers for not being compatible with universal radio transmitters

Answer (score 2):

1> The "4 in 1 chip" *does handle more protocols* than the CC2500. It has the CC2500, nRF24L01, A7105 and CYR all integrated in one package and allows you to bind with and use *Flysky, Spektrum, HUBSAN, DSM2, DEVO, J6PRO, ESKY, HISKY, KN, V2X2 and ASSAN* receivers which you won't be able to do with just the CC2500.

2> Spektrum is basically a brand of high end radios. (At least they are high end for me)

Comment: PS: I have the TX12. It feels adequate. It is my second radio, was using a FS-i6 before. TX12 doesn't support Flysky, but it just felt like a steal. So I got a FrSky receiver for real cheap. I am happy with what I have. You would probably not need to use most of these protocols. FrSky based receivers are omnipresent nowadays. Most BNF/RTF crafts come with FrSky RX options nowadays, and you can always be careful while making stuff. Of course, if you believe that you may *end up flying a lot of drones, you might want to get a better radio with a 4 in 1 module*